# Postgres jsonb array: query for non-empty intersection

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Suppose I have a JSONB column called `value` in a table `t`, and inside of these blobs of JSON is a `tags` field which is a list of strings.

I'd like to make a query for any of these JSON blobs tagged `"foo"` or `"bar"`.

So suppose the table data looks like this:

```
value
---------------------
{"tags": ["other"]}
{"tags": ["foo", "quux"]}
{"tags": ["baz", "bar"]}
{"tags": ["bar", "foo"]}
{"tags": []}
```

I want to write some sort of query like this:

```
select value from t where value->'tags' NONEMPTY_INTERSECTION '["foo", "bar"]'
```

Such that the result will be:

```
value
-----------------------
{"tags": ["foo", "quux"]}
{"tags": ["baz", "bar"]}
{"tags": ["bar", "foo"]}
```

Is there an actual query that will accomplish this, and is there any way that it could possibly be fast?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [querying JSONB with array fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480863/querying-jsonb-with-array-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator I was looking for is `?|`, which can be used like so:

```
select t.value from t where value->'tags' ?| array['foo','bar'];
```

Tested as follows:

```
danburton=# select * from jsonb_test;
           value
---------------------------
 {"tags": ["foo"]}
 {"tags": ["other"]}
 {"tags": ["foo", "quux"]}
 {"tags": ["baz", "bar"]}
 {"tags": ["bar", "foo"]}
 {"tags": []}
(6 rows)

danburton=# select jsonb_test.value from jsonb_test where value->'tags' ?| array['foo','bar'];
           value
---------------------------
 {"tags": ["foo"]}
 {"tags": ["foo", "quux"]}
 {"tags": ["baz", "bar"]}
 {"tags": ["bar", "foo"]}
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.value
FROM t, jsonb_array_elements(t.value->'tags') tags
WHERE tags.value <@ '["foo", "bar"]'::jsonb;
```