# querying JSONB with array fields

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

If I have a `jsonb` column called `value` with fields such as:

```
{"id": "5e367554-bf4e-4057-8089-a3a43c9470c0",
 "tags": ["principal", "reversal", "interest"],,, etc}
```

how would I find all the records containing given tags, e.g: 
if given: `["reversal", "interest"]`
it should find all records with either "reversal" or "interest" or both.

My experimentation got me to this abomination so far:

```
select value from account_balance_updated 
where value @> '{}' :: jsonb and value->>'tags' LIKE '%"principal"%';
```

of course this is completely wrong and inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out you can use cool jsonb operators described here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html

so original query doesn't have to change much:

```
select value from account_balance_updated 
where value @> '{}' :: jsonb and value->'tags' ?| array['reversal', 'interest'];
```

in my case I also needed to escape the `?` (`??|`) because I am using so called "prepared statement" where you pass query string and parameters to jdbc and question marks are like placeholders for params:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using PG 9.4+, you can use the `jsonb_array_elements()` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT abu.*
FROM account_balance_updated abu,
     jsonb_array_elements(abu.value->'tags') t
WHERE t.value <@ '["reversal", "interest"]'::jsonb;
```

Comment: eh... now I wonder if it's possible to achieve that by just modifying `where` part? Otherwise I will have to refactor some other parts of the code (that composes the whole query). So if I have a query that starts like `select value from account_balance_updated 
where value @> '{}' :: jsonb and value->> 'id' = '48c017c2-40c0-4462-ba2b-c2f176a2d086' and ...` could I achieve the same trick (as in your answer) by just appending some magic to query like this?

Comment: I did this `and value->'tags' ?| array['interest','reversal']` and it seems to be working

Comment: Without seeing the whole query it is difficult to say. In SQL there are often multiple solutions for a single problem. The optimal solution can usually be deduced from table structures, indexes, other query content, etc., but sometimes it is just trial-and-error.